integrating conan with existing cmake project
I want to use conan in an existing CMake project. I have the conanfile.txt in the root directory and run conan install . --build=missing --output-folder=build/conan, but I don't know how to get CMake to find the dependencies it has built/downloaded.
I am using the VSCode CMake extension and it runs this command to generate:
/usr/bin/cmake --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/g++ -S/home/me/myproject -B/home/me/myproject/build/Debug -G Ninja
conanfile.txt
[requires]
boost/1.85.0
fmt/10.2.1
openssl/3.0.9
cryptopp/8.9.0

[generators]
CMakeDeps

Also, I am using find_package in CMake to find them.

You need to use the CMakeToolchain generator and then use -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake or better the cmake --preset conan-default/conan-release. Also better to use the [layout] with cmake_layout and forget about the --output-folder argument

You also need to align the dependencies arguments. If you want to build in Debug, then you need to pass the right arguments to conan install, like conan install ... -s build_type=Debug. Likewise, if those compilers are not the default ones in the system (in that case you wouldn't need to define them in command line), better define them in a profile file too, in the [buildenv] section as CC/CXX env-vars, or with [conf] like tools.build:compiler_executables. Check the getting started tutorial: https://docs.conan.io/2/tutorial/consuming_packages/build_simple_cmake_project.html
